# Error in FIRST_VALUE OVER PARTITION BY ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and want to create a column named "firstprice" and "lastprice" from a list. first price partitioned by part number, order by extracted registration year (of the price of the part). My code seem to overlook the ORDER BY code, since I only get First_Value (Price) of the item. (and not ordered by year)

```sql
SELECT 
Prices."Part",
Prices."Price",
Prices."RegDt"
CAST(FIRST_VALUE("Price" IGNORE NULLS) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY PB."Part" ORDER BY (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM(Prices."RegDt"))))AS INTEGER) AS "FirstPrice",  

CAST(LAST_VALUE("Price" IGNORE NULLS) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY PB."Part" ORDER BY (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM(Prices."RegDt"))))AS INTEGER) AS "FirstPrice",  

FROM Prices
```

Expected output is first price registered that year, but I only get first price for that item (not showing per year)

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results. You should be getting a price from the first year, though if there is more than one price that year then which of those you get is indeterminate. You aren't selecting/grouping by the year, so you aren't asking for 'per year' values. It's unclear if that is what you want. (Not related, but if you have a choice, I'd suggest you avoid using quoted identifiers as they'll cause you pain at some point...)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have changed my code as following below and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expected output is first price registered that year

So you need to add year to `partition` clause. I also defined window clause for `last_value`, otherwise it is unbounded preceding and current row and we want data from next rows here:

```
select part, price, regdt, 
       first_value(price) over (partition by part, extract (year from(regdt))
                                order by regdt) fp,
       last_value(price) over (partition by part, extract (year from(regdt))
                               order by regdt 
                               range between current row 
                                         and interval '1' year following ) lp
  from prices
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1aa891f493ee14e658007c502de46012)</sup>**